# Perforce: Propagate changes from a file to another

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

How can I take changes from a file that I have in my depot and apply it to a file in my current workspace.

Consider the following scenario.

I have a branch A where I have submitted some changes to files a1, a2 and a3. The change number associated for this submission is 123.

Now I am in another branch B that I am currently working on. I have to take the changes of file A/a1 that I made as a part of change number 123 and apply it to B/a1.

I tried using [perforce-integrate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrate.html), but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: What combinations of integrate commands did you try?

Answer (score 1):

To propagate all of change 123 from A to B:

```
p4 integ A/...@123,123 B/...
p4 resolve -am
p4 resolve                    # (if needed)
p4 submit
```

To propagate ONLY a1@123,123:

```
p4 integ A/a1@123,123 B/a1
p4 resolve -am
p4 resolve                   # (if needed)
p4 submit
```

If any part of this does not work, an error message will be displayed indicating what you need to correct in order to make it work.